# How to write Python Code in Django

Tags: python, django

This is an embarrassingly simple question. I'm trying to understand how to incorporate a simple Python function in the first Django app I'm building. Here is my views.py file...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from noticeboard.models import Listings
from django.views import generic
from django.template import Context

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'listings/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_listings'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Listings.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Listings
    template_name = 'listings/listings_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'listing'
```

In the Listings model, I have the following field:

```
listing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to write a function that makes sure the listing variable is all upper case - I know how to write the function - I just don't know how to incorporate it into the views.py file!

Comment: You say you want to "make sure the listing variable is all upper case" - do you mean that you're planning to accept input and want to uppercase it prior to saving?  The views you're using here handle displaying information that's already in your database, but not creation or updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

1. Pass the variable through the `upper` template filter in the html template, like so:

   ```
   {{ listing.listing|upper }}
   ```

   ... as jpic said.  Here, the context object is "listing", and its attribute that you want to upcase is listing.listing.
2. Create a method on the model that returns that attribute as all upper case:

   ```
   class Listing(models.Model):
       def uppercase_listing(self):
          return self.listing.upper()
   ```

   and then use it in the template, like so:

   ```
   {{ listing.uppercase_listing }}
   ```

   Note that you may only have methods that do not take any arguments, as there is no way to pass arguments in an implied method call in a Django template.
3. Write a custom template tag or filter.  For this simple use (making a variable uppercase) it would be overkill as there already exists a built-in filter for that (what jpic pointed out).  But if you wanted some kind of custom changes, then a custom tag or filter might be appropriate.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/

So to sum up, you would call a function from your template by:

- attaching it to a model and referencing it that way
- writing a custom tag or template.

But in your case you don't have to, an existing built-in filter already exists that does what you want.

Generally speaking, django doesn't encourage any code going into the templates.  It tries to limit what goes in there into fairly declarative type statements.  The goal is to put all the logic into the model, view, and other python code, and just reference the pre-calculated values from the templates.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the [`upper` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#upper) ?

No need to write any pure python to display a view context variable in uppercase ...

Comment: Great, I was unaware Django had this feature!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from defining your own custom methods in the generic class, or defining them in another file and importing them into views. For example:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'listings/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_listings'

    def your_method_here(self, listing_object):
        # do your uppercase checking stuff here
        # don't forget to .save() your listing_object if you change it to uppercase!

    def get_queryset(self):
        for listing_object in Listings.objects.all()
            self.your_method_here(listing_object)
        return Listings.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
```

You could also do it as a normal function, and not a method, but that's really up to you.

Of course, some of the other suggestions are probably much better at solving the actual problem (uppercase filtering), but since you asked about calling functions/methods inside the views.py file, that's the answer.